# Computing pullbacks of certain function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $I^3 : [0, 1]^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, I^3(x) = x$. Define $I^3 _{(i, \alpha)} : [0, 1]^2 \to [0, 1]^3, \alpha \in \{0, 1\}$ like that : $$I^3_{(1, a)}(x^1, x^2) = I^3(\alpha, x^1, x^2), I^3_{(2, a)}(x^1, x^2) = I^3(x^1, \alpha, x^2), I^3_{(3, a)}(x^1, x^2) = I^3( x^1, x^2, \alpha).$$

I would like to compute pullbacks $(I^3_{i, \alpha})^*(dx^1 \wedge dx^2)$, however I am lost in what is happening here. How could I start computing something simpler eg. $(I^3_{1, \alpha})^*(dx^2)$?

Comment: $I^3$ is just the identity function, so $I^3{(i,\alpha)}$ is just just the inclusion map of the face $x^i=\alpha$. What makes the notation so confounding is the use of variables $x^1,x^2$ in whatever slots they happen to go. So, for example, in $I^3_{(1,\alpha)}$, $x^1$ plays the role of $x^2$ and $x^2$ plays the role of $x^3$. I personally would have used $(u,v)$ as my coordinates on $[0,1]^2$, not $(x^1,x^2)$.

Comment: At any rate, to help you out, $(I^3_{(1,\alpha)})^*dx^2 = dx^1$, $(I^3_{(1,\alpha)})^*dx^3 = dx^2$, and $(I^3_{(1,\alpha)})^*dx^1 = 0$. But if you had a more interesting function with the pullback, you'd have to set $x^1=\alpha$ in it. I think you're better off switching variables as I suggested :) [Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* is the my least favorite of his texts. Unless this is someone else's rendition of the notation.]

Comment: Thank you. Can I just write that eg $(I_{1,\alpha})^*(dx^1 \wedge dx^2) = 0 \wedge dx^1 = 0, (I_{3,\alpha})^*(dx^1 \wedge dx^2) = dx^1 \wedge dx^2$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(I^3_{(1,\alpha)})^*dx^1 = 0 \\
(I^3_{(1,\alpha)})^*dx^2 = dx^1 \\
(I^3_{(1,\alpha)})^*dx^3 = dx^2 \\
(I^3_{(2,\alpha)})^*dx^1 = dx^1 \\
(I^3_{(2,\alpha)})^*dx^2 = 0 \\
(I^3_{(2,\alpha)})^*dx^3 = dx^2 \\
(I^3_{(3,\alpha)})^*dx^1 = dx^1 \\
(I^3_{(3,\alpha)})^*dx^2 = dx^2 \\
(I^3_{(3,\alpha)})^*dx^3 = 0 \\
(I^3_{(1,\alpha)})^∗(dx^1∧dx^2)=0∧dx^1=0 \\
(I^3_{(2,\alpha)})^*(dx^1 \wedge dx^2) = dx^1 \wedge 0 = 0 \\
(I^3_{(3,\alpha)})^∗(dx^1∧dx^2)=dx^1∧dx^2
$